# Подскажите 3D-слайдер на jQuery, поддерживающий скролл на мобильной версии

Tags: jquery, slider

Вот нашел наиболее подходящий для моих нужд слайдер - https://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel, но он не поддерживает скролл на мобильном девайсе.

Подскажите подобный 3D-слайдер, который можно скроллить на мобилке.

Или, может, как-то адаптировать этот можно?

Answer (score 1):

Часто использую [LightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/), удобный и много опций\настроек.

Comment: Спасибо, но нужен именно такого типа, чтобы увеличивалась центральная картинка

Comment: @Сергей, у слайдера есть "плагин" [lightGallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/), подключить к слайдеру и всё.

Comment: что-то не получается заставить слайдер листать пальцем на мобилке. Нужно просто подключить плагин mousewheel? Не работает так

Comment: вы пишете "у слайдера есть "плагин" lightGallery, подключить к слайдеру и всё", но ведь это совсем другой слайдер, а мне нужен именно https://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel, но с возможностью пролистывания пальцем на тачскрине.